# why doesn't my Cython installation import?

Tags: python, cpython

I want to use Cython, and did the following:

```
$ pip install Cython
    Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /anaconda3/envs/learn/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.27.3)
```

But then it gives this error:

```
In [1]: cimport numpy as np                                                                                                    
  File "<ipython-input-1-9e1f0d02d1fa>", line 1
    cimport numpy as np
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [2]:
```

After installing, what else needs to be done to use it?

Comment: Is your interactive shell using the same env as the anaconda env path above?

Comment: `cimport` should be `import`?

Comment: it has to be 'cimport'

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to work in ipython or a jupyter enviornment (which it looks like you are) you'll first need to load the Cython extension : `%load_ext Cython`.

You then need to use `%%cython` to define a magic cell in which you can call your cython code:

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
```